# correct way to exclude certain characters from crypto.randomBytes

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

i have the following code, based on http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.6.9/api/crypto.html#randomBytes

```
crypto.randomBytes 32, (ex, buf) ->
  user.tokenString = buf.toString("hex")
  user.tokenExpires = Date.now() + TOKEN_TIME
  next()
```

i am using this to generate a tokenString to use for a node.js/express user validation.

in some cases the tokenString generated includes '/' forward slash character, and this breaks my routes, for example, tokenString if the tokenString is like '`$2a$10$OYJn2r/Ts.guyWqx7iJTwO8cij80m.uIQV9nJgTt18nqu8lT8OqPe`' it can't find `/user/activate/$2a$10$OYJn2r` and i get an 404 error

is there a more direct way to exclude certain characters from being included when generating the crypto.randomBytes?

Comment: Are you sure this is the code you're using? Reading this again, `buf.toString("hex")` specifies that the resulting string is the buffer where two characters encode each leter. It should only be in the range 0-9a-f and should work.

Comment: Yep, I just performed 1000 iterations of getting random bytes and converting them toString("hex"), all of them match [a-f0-9] .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crypto.randomBytes generates random *bytes* . That has nothing to do with characters, characters are determined by the way we *look* at the bytes.

For example:

```
user.tokenString = buf.toString("hex")
```

Would convert the buffer to a string (where two characters represent each byte), in the character range `0-9a-f`

Another (might be more suiting approach is to use a more compact encoding. Base64Url is an encoding that provides string encoding that is URL/Filename safe

```
user.tokenString = base64url(buf)
```

Here is [an NPM package you can use for it](https://npmjs.org/package/base64url).

Other than that, your code seems fine. If you were to call `.toString()` without specifying `"hex"` or specifying something like `"ascii"` for example, it would break just like in your question description.

Comment: @khinester I updated my answer to be more relevant to the issue. If you think it solved your issue please consider accepting it.

Comment: yes, i tried to accept it yesterday, but had to wait. thanks for the input.